# Create a Timer in MySQL

Tags: mysql, timer

I have a backup system..... that backs up a folder every 5 minutes. The backup can be assigned to any device using its IP Address. But once a week or once a month that device is rebooted, and we want to turn the backup off every week or month on a certain time for certain seconds. Creating the database table shouldn't be a problem, I was wondering if there is any way we can do this in a function

The Tables are structured as below

**Device**

```
Id     BIGINT(20),    //Auto Increment Id of the Device
Name   VARCHAR(255),  //Name of the device
Backup TINYINT(1)     //Boolean to represent weather the device is backed or not
```

**TurnOffBackup**

```
Id        BIGINT(20),  //Id of the Table
deviceId  BIGINT(20),  //DeviceId Foriegn Key
weekDay    TINYINT(1), //The week day to turn it off
monthDate INT(2),      //The month date to turn it off
fortime   BIGINT(20)   //The number of seconds to turn the device off for
```

At the moment my select for devices to be backedup are as follows

```
SELECT * FROM Device WHERE backup=1
```

What i wana achieve is

```
SELECT * FROM Device WHERE backup=1 AND TURNBACKUPOFF(Device.Id)=0
```

Any idea how i would do this or should i be considiring doing this in code rather than in a MySQL Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `id INT` and `backupEnabled BOOLEAN`, and use a cron script or Quartz to enable/disable backups. More precisely, I'd update this from the same script which is causing the reboot. Duplicating the time of reboot is useless and error-prone.

Comment: Yea but the device is defined by IP Address. And backups are ran over network not locally so im not sure about the script thing.